# Reg exp for floating number

Tags: regex

I need a reg exp that should match the below pattern:

1. Can start with and can end with either a dot or a number(., .1,       .1., 1, 1., 1.1)
2. Only one dot is allowed between two numbers(1.1)
3. Also, dot is not mandatory(123)

I tried using `(^[\d.\]?|[0-9]*\.|[0-9]+|[0-9]+)`, but not working.
It matches n number of dots and not matching number after dot

Comment: Do you mean like this? `^\.?(?:\d+\.?)*$` https://regex101.com/r/Z6RO3Z/1

Comment: It may be easier to just attempt to parse the string as a number

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot @The fourth bird.

Comment: Can it  accept empty values?

Comment: @Thefourthbird Can you help me fix this regex https://regex101.com/r/rkhAKx/1 ?

Comment: @AmrKeleg I have posted an answer. It that solving your problem? https://regex101.com/r/HZBvYb/2

Comment: Yes, it does solve it perfectly.
I am not the question writer.
I am just enthusiast about regex and wanted to know how to solve it myself.
I wrote a regex but it seems like it's matching invalid inputs also.

Comment: No, it can't accept empty values

Comment: @VishalKumar The last pattern does not match an empty string and I have used that in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is the accept validation

`^(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)$`

Expanded

```
 ^ 
 (?:
      \d+ 
      (?: \. \d* )?
   |  
      \. \d+ 
 )
 $
```

This is the validation after key press

`^(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.(?:\d+)?)$`

Answer (score 0):

You get all the matches because you use 3 alternations (from which the last 2 are the same `[0-9]+`)

The first part of the alternation asserts the start of the string`^` and is actually a character class `^[.\]?|[0-9]*` repeating 0+ times matching any of the listed characters `.]?|` or a range 0-9.

After that it requires to match a dot which is the last dot in the string because it can also be matched in the character class. Then the other alternation matches any digits at the end.

If a positive lookahead is supported and empty matches are not allowed you could use a positive lookahead to check if there is atleast a digit or dot present.

Then match an optional dot an use a looping pattern to match 1+ digits followed by an optional dot.

```
^(?=[.\d])\.?(?:\d+\.?)*$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=[.\d])` Assert either a dot or digit
- `\.?` Match optional dot
- `(?:\d+\.?)*` Repeat 0+ times matching 1+ digit and an optional dot
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/l7tMRA/1)

Comment: Can it match `.4.4.4.`  ?

Comment: I guess so `and can end with either a dot or a number`

Answer (score 0):

I have used this regex:

```
^((\d*\.)(\d+\.)*)?\d*$
```

My idea is:

- Match all digits at the start of the string.
- Match the first dot.
- From now on, at least one digit must be matched before a new dot (\d+\.)*.
- The steps listed above are all optional.
- Finally, match any number of digits \d*.
- Use ^ and $ to prevent intermediate matches in the string.

Comment: The pattern also matches an empty string.